# Overriding already overridden methods in derived class

Tags: java, android

I have a class `CarSettingsAdapter` that extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.
In that class I have a overridden method that return item of type CarSettings

```
@Override
    public CarSettings getItem(int position) {
        return carSettingsList.get(position);
    }
```

Now I creating a new class that extends class `CarSettingsAdapter` but I want it to return my own type - let say `MyTypeB`

```
public class NewCarSettings extends CarSettings {

@Override
    public MyTypeB getItem(int position) {
        return typeBList.get(position);
    }
}
```

I cant override it, I getting an compile error - `The return type is incompatible with CarSettingsAdapter.getItem(int)`.

I want to use all the logic of `CarSettingsAdapter`, that's why I extends it, but also to override the basic methods. How can I do it?

Comment: If you change the method signature, by definition you aren't overriding it, you're creating a new method.

Comment: What is the type hierarchy of NewTypeB? This will only work if it is a subtype of CarSettings.

Comment: @AndyTurner No the `NewTypeB` is not subtype of `CarSettings`. So how can I extends the class `CarSettingsAdapter` and add a little changes ... I don't want to copy 95% of the code to my new class

Comment: @AlexOpent Well, nothing is stopping you from adding a method which returns a `MyTypeB` to the class, but it either can't be called `getItem` or it must have a different parameters. However, if it is going to *override* the method, it must return a `CarSettings` or one of its subtype. The reason for this restriction is that you can pass an instance of `NewCarSettings` to any method expecting an instance of `CarSettings`, which then expects to get back an instance of `CarSettings` if it calls `getItem`. If you were able to return any other type, you would get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Can't you have another method `getMyNewItem()` to return your new value ? You can't use polymorphism with his but you still inherit all the other methods from `CarSettingsAdapter` (or)  You can make your `MyTypeB` a sub-class of `CarSettings` (or) if you have access to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, you can change `getItem()'s` return type to `Object`. Last one is merely a work around not a good design solution though as you've to make some `instanceof` checks to know about the object you're getting from that method

Comment: If I create a new method that returns `MyTypeB` then all the adapter logic wont work, because when I setting the adapter it calls to `getItem` method to display the item, so creating a new method wont help me.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an intermediate class that uses generics. For example `CustomSettingsAdapter<T> extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

That way your `getItem()` method could return `T`.

Then you put the common logic in that class and create your new classes like this:

- `CarSettingsAdapter extends CustomSettingsAdapter<CarSettings>`
- `NewCarSettingsAdapter extends CustomSettingsAdapter<NewCarSettings>`